# async series and parallel methods strange behaviour

Tags: node.js

```
var func1 = function(){ console.log('function 1'); };    
var func2 = function(){ console.log('function 2'); };

async.series([func1, func2]); // output: function 1    
async.parallel([func1, func2]); // output : function 1 // function 2
```

why func2 is not been called in first case ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why func2 is not been called in first case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions need to know when the function has finished, and this is done via a `next` callback:

```
var func1 = function(next){ console.log('function 1'); next(); };    
var func2 = function(next){ console.log('function 2'); next(); };

async.series([func1, func2]); // output: function 1  // function 2   
async.parallel([func1, func2]); // output : function 1 // function 2
```

Comment: but then how async.parallel() produces correct output ? (still without having a callback)

Comment: For parallel, async uses the done() to trigger an 'all finished' callback. While you see the print statements, this would have failed in your example. Done() is not needed to simply start all your functions running.